# Is it mandatory to travel to Canada on the exact dates specified in the visa?

Tags: visas, canada

I'm awaiting my Canadian visitor visa. I requested it to be from 5th of June to 7th of July, but the ticket got very expensive for those dates, therefore I might need to go a bit later (Jun 12 to Jul 10).

Will this cause a problem for me? Must the visa start being used on the 5th or this little difference doesn't cause a problem?

Comment: Do you have the visa yet? Does it give dates of validity?

Comment: @Aborted the visa *will* have an expiration date, and you will need to enter Canada on our before that date.

Comment: @Aborted and all here , does a Canadian visa have an entry date ?? Like if I apply to fly there on say 6th of July, would they have a start date as 6th July or would it be the printing date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said this in a comment, but now I've got a proper citation, so here's a proper answer.

Canadian visas (like every other visa I'm familiar with) do indeed have an expiration date.  This is the date *by which you must travel to Canada to seek entry.*  As you note in your comment, the duration of stay is not affected by the expiration of the visa.

> The expiry date on the TRV is the date by which the visa must be used to seek admission into Canada. If the visa is not used on or before that date, it ceases to be valid.

"TRV" means "Temporary resident visa"

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/tools/temp/visa/validity/expiry.asp

Comment: @Aborted It depends entirely on the expiration date printed on your visa.  If I were you, I would probably call the consulate to tell them of my change of plans.  If not, you'll just have to hope that they give you a big enough window.

Comment: @Aborted I just did an image search for *Canadian single entry visa* which turned up a couple that were both valid for about six months, though they were rather old, and policies may have changed. Still, your chances look good. If they give you a multiple-entry visa it will certainly be valid for at least a few months, and perhaps as long as ten years.  Do let us know.

Answer (score 1):

There should be **an expiration date on your visa that tells you of the final day you can travel in Canada**, regardless of the days you requested on your application. If you're within the window of validity, you should be good to go.

Your visa is *typically* good for six months – flights get delayed, cancelled, shifted around and governments recognize that. Like all countries it's entirely dependent on the border guard to issue a final date you can stay in the country, regardless of your visa expiration. They can give you until the final day of your visa, or the day after your departure ticket. It's pretty much up to them.

Finally and most importantly, enjoy your stay in Canada this summer!

Source: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016&top=16